# Disclosure and publishing of 'catch and kill' practices favouring a presidential candidate

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, campaign-finance

[Catch and kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_and_kill) is the practice by a media outlet to buy the right to a negative story about someone and not publish it so that the story doesn't go public.

Suppose this technique was used by a newspaper regarding a negative story about a presidential candidate, then that might constitute a campaign contribution. Indeed, the [Federal Election Committee (FEC) states](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/candidate-taking-receipts/types-contributions/):

> A contribution is anything of value given, loaned or advanced to influence a federal election. It is important to understand which receipts are considered contributions because:

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_finance_in_the_United_States#Disclosure_rules), campaign contributions have to be reported to the FEC, which publishes a database of those contributions.

If the aforementioned practice is indeed a contribution, to what extent does it have to be disclosed (by the newspaper) and to what extent does the FEC publish about the contribution?

Specifically, does the contribution disclosure only include the amount of money involved (assuming the amount is high enough that it requires disclosing) or does it have to be so detailed that it reveals the *catch and kill* practice?

**Edit:**

In the comments, it has been pointed out that there have not yet been any court rulings on this matter. Since the subject [has been in the news a lot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22catch+and+kill%22), is there a consensus among (legal) scholars regarding the questions above? If there is no consensus, what reasons are there for the difference in opinion?

Comment: I think this is better asked at [Law.SE], since it's a specific legal question about campaign finance laws.  I'm not going to vote to close it as off-topic because it _is_ about "political processes", but I think we won't be able to provide a good answer.

Comment: This is going to be a bad question anywhere, as we are essentially speculating on an area of law where this exact question has not previously arisen.  In particular, Trump may have paid with his own funds rather than campaign funds.  Are we now saying that personal expenditures that might help a campaign must be counted as in-kind transfers from the candidate to the campaign?  Taken to extremes, this might be invasive.  For example, Christ Christie's weight loss procedure might help his campaign by making him look more fit.  Was it a campaign contribution?

Comment: @Brythan, Re *"Chris Christie's weight loss procedure might help..."*:  there's more than a reasonable doubt that Christie's surgery was undertaken to improve his health, and probably would have occurred even if there was no campaign.  OTOH, *"David Dennison's"* six or seven figure hush fund for various mistresses would be all the more remarkable in the absence of a campaign.

Comment: @Brythan surely campaign finance law isn't just speculation. There have been many campaigns so there's likely to be precedent (though perhaps not directly about catch and kill). For example, [pertaining to travel expenses.](https://www.fec.gov/updates/fec-reaches-settlement-with-rev-al-sharpton-sharpton-2004-and-non-profit-corporation/)

Comment: What if Trump claims that he paid the money not for campaign purposes but to either hide it from his wife or to protect his business.  Then it's not a campaign expense.  Note that the Sharpton example involved money paid *by* the campaign being used for non-campaign expenses.  Here, the claim is the reverse.  That this was a campaign expense but was not listed as such and that it was implicitly donated or at least loaned to the campaign.  The closest comparable is the [Ensign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ensign_scandal) situation, but he resigned and it didn't go to court.

Comment: @Brythan much as the news seems to revolve around mr. Trump, this question is about campaign finance, not one individual (campaign).

Comment: Trump is the first time that "catch and kill" has ever been questioned from a campaign finance standpoint.  It is possible that the practice was used previously in an election capacity.  But if so, no one made an issue of it.  Also, this may fall under endorsements exception.  Extending from this particular, possibly precedent-setting instance to a general policy is going to be difficult without a first case.  Thus that extension makes it more speculative, not less.  If you want less speculative, you will have to drop "catch and kill" and switch to a more common problem, like travel expenses.

Comment: Answers can only be speculative at this point due to lack of precedent, as you yourself note, so voting to close. If you phrase it as to ask what scholars might have said in connection to this... perhaps it would be ok.

Comment: @Fizz I have edited the question to acknowledge the lack of legal precedent and rephrased to ask if there is a consensus and if there isn't, what the reasons exist for the difference(s) in view point on the matter.

Comment: Until this goes to trial (if ever) I think we can only all speculate.

Comment: Even then, there's going to be so many ancillary bits of data involved with this that I don't think there even could be a universal answer. It's all going to be heavily based on context and the specifics of the particular case in question.

Comment: I'm going to down-vote because the crux of the question is not something that requires a question. You'd report it just like you would any other kind of "in kind contribution." I don't see any magic about this scenario that would require a different process. A simple Google search of "how are in-kind contributions reported" immediately brings up a hit on the FEC site with instructions and illustrations. OP did not exert even minimal attempts to find out the answer. 
https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/filing-reports/in-kind-contributions/

Comment: @PoloHoleSet that doesn't answer what the FEC publishes about that report. If you're trying to keep a secret then reporting it to some institution which publishes your secret poses a problem. The second part of my question is about that.

Comment: You are asking about what detail has to be reported via disclosure. Everything filed from the disclosure form is not only put into the FEC database, but you can click on any individual contribution transaction and see a .pdf of the form filed. Why would you think that reporting/disclosure is kept secret?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I'm not very familiar with the procedures and rules of the FEC, that's why I asked the question. If you're sure that all the reports are published verbatim then that answers a big part of the question, so feel free to post that as answer. The reason I asked about the catch and kill is because that's how I heard about it in the media.

Comment: @Brythan re: chris christie's weight loss surgery - it would be a possible campaign contribution if it was done for free, but I'm assuming that he paid for it.

Comment: @DavidRice  But the question is inspired by Trump paying blackmail.  I.e. Trump also paid for it.

Comment: @Brythan actually, Trump isn't mentioned in the question explicitly. The question is asked in general, but it has come to my attention via the news, specifically, the National Inquirer story. The question itself doesn't rely on that case.

Comment: Right.  And I provided a potential example of another expense that might be paid by a candidate while campaigning.  Which you should support, since your claim is that this example is not about Trump and the National Enquirer (yes, they use the British spelling).  My example is exactly the same principle.  So why is it clear that Christie would not have to report but Trump did have to report?  Which is essentially the claim being made.

Comment: @Brythan I am not claiming anything about Christie's case. I merely asked about the catch and kill practice because I saw it in the news and it was reported that the situation may cause problems with the FEC. I did a little bit of research, but I cannot put the rules into context nor do I know of possible exceptions or jurisprudence, hence my question here.

Comment: @Brythan It looks like AMI spent money to bury the story and it was not Donald Trump doing it himself, which seems like a contribution.  https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/21/us/politics/trump-michael-cohen-american-media.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't illegal to pay someone for exclusive rights to a story and then choose not to publish it. It is, however, illegal to [coordinate with a presidential campaign](https://www.thedailybeast.com/national-enquirer-publisher-its-our-first-amendment-right-to-silence-karen-mcdougal-over-trump) to provide an [in-kind corporate contribution](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/29/us/politics/trump-national-enquirer-david-pecker.html) for the purpose of influencing a presidential election.

Our armchair speculation has been rendered moot, however, as David Pecker, CEO of AMI, has essentially admitted to committing a crime by [accepting legal immunity from Mueller](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2018/08/donald-trump-national-enquirer-allies-defect-david-pecker-michael-cohen) in return for his cooperation in the case against Trump.

Comment: I welcome the links, but this doesn't really answer the question of how such coordination would have to be reported to the FEC. If I understand correctly (from your first link), such an '*in-kind corporate contribution*' is only illegal if not reported.

Comment: It would also be illegal if it was over the campaign contribution limit of $2,700.

Comment: I also wondered if it could be considered fraud to buy "rights to publish" with no intent to do so.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect.  It is not necessary to allocute to accept legal immunity.  Legal immunity only says that one can't be prosecuted.  It is not an admission of guilt.  At most, it is an admission that someone might perceive (rightly or wrongly) guilt.